# Symfony3 foreign key relation entities not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables `backup_policy` and `backup_settings`. `backup_policy` has a foreign key field called `backup_settings_id` with is mapped with `backup_settings` `id` field. This is the query executed to create the relation between two tables

```
ALTER TABLE `backup_policy_scheduler`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`backup_policy_id`) REFERENCES `backup_policy` (`id`)
```

Now the problem is, when I try this code, the screen keep on loading and gives me maximum execution error.

```
$repository=$this->getDoctrine()>getRepository('AppBundle:BackupPolicy');
$settings = $repository->findAll();
```

When I prepare a sql statement and do fetchAll() it fetches the result.

When I try to insert record it gives me the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\BackupPolicy::setBackupSettings() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\BackupSettings, string given, called in /var/www/symfonyproject/src/AppBundle/Controller/BackupPolicyController.php on line 46

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
* BackupPolicy
*
* @ORM\Table(name="backup_policy")
  *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\BackupPolicyRepository")
*/
class BackupPolicy
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \BackupSettings
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BackupSettings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="backup_settings_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $backupSettings;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set backupSettings
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BackupSettings $backupSettings
 *
 * @return BackupPolicy
 */
public function setBackupSettings(\AppBundle\Entity\BackupSettings $backupSettings = null)
{
    $this->backupSettings = $backupSettings;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get backupSettings
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\BackupSettings
 */
public function getBackupSettings()
{
    return $this->backupSettings;
}
}
```

Comment: Your error is that you try to assign $this->backupSettings with a string. In your controller line 46. This is no related to the foreignn key or the mapping.

Show your controller.

Comment: Yes, u r right. I am inserting a string only. I am getting this when I insert into the backup_settings table. But why even findAll() dosen't work ?

Comment: Please show the Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only insert a BackupSettings entity.

In your controller line 46.

Not :

```
$backupPolicy->setBackupSettings('setting1');
```

But something like :

```
$repo=$this->getDoctrine()>getRepository('AppBundle:BackupSetting');
$backupPolicy->setBackupSettings($repo->findOneBy(array('name'=>'setting1'));
```

Comment: Its working! I could insert the data into backup_policy table. But still fetching the data from backup_policy table doesn't work. `$repository=$this->getDoctrine()>getRepository('AppBundle:BackupPolicy');
 $settings = $repository->findAll();`

Comment: Is it beacause of your '>' between getDoctrine() and getRepository() ?

Comment: Two records. I think it does't have issues with data.

Comment: OK, sorry but no idea.